# How to make a GridRow tappable in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

When using a Grid rather than a List, in SwiftUI, we lose some of the tapping functionality that Lists had built-in. We can try to re-create it by using the onTapGesture method on the GridRow; however, it only seems to detect the taps on visible children of the GridRow.

Here's an example that illustrates this.

```
struct GridTest: View {
    @State private var tapCount: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Grid(horizontalSpacing: 50) {
            GridRow {
                Text("This\nrow was\ntapped")
                Text("\(tapCount) times")
            }
            .background(.yellow)
            .onTapGesture { tapCount += 1 }
        }.background(.green)
    }
}
```

[image]

The yellow areas will increment the counter, but the green areas (which I would have considered part of the Grid Row) do not.

Is there a good way of correcting this so that a tap anywhere in the frame of the GridRow would trigger the onTapGesture method?

Comment: You can add an `.onTapGesture` to the `Grid` itself.  Then the green areas would accept a tap, but it would be the same for all rows since the tap gesture belongs to the Grid and not the GridRow.

Comment: I have a feeling that something could maybe be done with a GeometryReader on the Grid (to get the Grid frame) and use that info to position and size some sort of uncropped background control under the last cell, spanning over to the first one. But I'm not experienced enough with this stuff to do it.